# Team City Conditional Build Execution

Tags: teamcity

I want to create a one-click release build. I am fine creating multiple build configurations and linking them together or building everything in one build configuration.

Module Dependencies are mentioned below:
Module C depends upon module A and B. Module D depends upon module C.

A > C > D
B > C

There could be instances where nothing has been changed on module A or B. If nothing has been changed in a module, I do not want to build and release them as it was already released in past. This would have been simple if I need to build all the modules every time which is not the case.

Let us consider a scenario that there is a change in module B. In this case, I only want to build module B, C & D (but not A).

Is there a way this could be achieved with build step or parameters or by any other means in Team City?

Comment: just make corresponding artifact dependencies and trigger builds by those dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Snapshot Dependencies enable the checkbox

`Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` 
`Only use successful builds from suitable ones`

I recommend using **Artifact Dependencies** with **Snapshot Dependencies**.

Enable the follows settings
`Build from the same chain`
`Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` 
`Only use successful builds from suitable ones`

Then the TC will not build some of build chain if no chainges

Comment: I've been waiting it also

Comment: @TarunSingh if the answer helped you can accept it and vote.

Comment: I could get it working with snapshot dependencies only.